# Setting a color for "World" doesn't work

Tags: node-editor, world

I would like to have a pure white background in my animation.

When I set the color of the World in the World Panel to white, nothing works.

[Even the "Preview" stays pitch black.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZA6y.jpg)

**How do I change the color of the background "World"?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your world surface node is using the **Emission** node inaccurately, use the <kbd>Background</kbd> node instead in place of it.

Comment: Awesome, boss, thanks

Comment: Glad I could help. If my answer helped your problem please consider marking my answer post as the thread solution.